# Client to Server messages : Flaw printing

Tags: c

The client sends 3 messages to the server.

```
echo "-------------------------" | nc localhost 90
echo "-------------------------" | nc localhost 90
echo "-------------------------" | nc localhost 90
```

The server prints the first message properly. 
However fails to print the 2nd and 3rd messages properly.

```
gcc test.c && ./a.out 
-------------------------
����-------------------------
����-------------------------
```

Problematic Portion of the Code :

```
for (;;) {

Me_and_Them = accept(Path_to_Me, (struct sockaddr *) &Their_Address, &sin_len);

char Their_Message[50];

size_t Bytes_To_Read;
Bytes_To_Read = sizeof(Their_Message);

ssize_t Bytes_Read;
Bytes_Read = read( Me_and_Them, Their_Message, Bytes_To_Read );

fputs(Their_Message, stdout);

close(Me_and_Them);

}
```

Comment: Most likely it’s not the next messages, it’s you printing data without adding a null terminator so it goes out of the read data bounds and garbage is printed.

Comment: @Sami Kushmonen, I added the `null` and the problem has been resolved.  `char* With_Null;
 With_Null = malloc( strlen(Their_Message) + 1);
 strcpy(With_Null, Their_Message);

 fputs(With_Null, stdout);` If you post your comment as an answer, I will likely to select it as the "chosen answer".

Comment: That is unnecessary and won’t work. You can’t use `strcpy` if you don’t have the null there. Just use `Their_Message[Bytes_Read] = 0` assuming the buffer is big enough.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen, Perhaps `read()` is adding a `Null` ? Because the code I posted in my comment above, is working properly with the same test from the question.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen, I also tried it with your solution : `Their_Message[Bytes_Read] = 0; fputs(Their_Message, stdout);` and it too seems to be working properly.  Thank you for all the information.

Comment: `read` will never add it, but “garbage” can also manifest as a zero byte and it may seem like it works